# Miama Nueva Font not found

Tags: fonts

I am running this code with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{miama}

\begin{document}

\fmmfamily

Some text.

\end{document}
```

It compiles but produces no pdf, and there is this 'problem' : `The miama-t source file could not be found.` and `PK font miama-t1 could not be created.` Any idea ?

Comment: I don't know about LuaLaTeX but your code is for LaTeX document... not for XeLaTeX that needs commands like : `\usepackage{xltxtra}` and
`\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}` or
`\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}`

Comment: @koleygr `xltxtra` would be for XeLaTeX, but `fontspec` is sufficient (and the relevant package).

Comment: To your actual problem: You should not use `fontenc` with `T1` with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX.

Comment: While T1-encoding is not a suitable encoding for lualatex, the document in itself should nevertheless compile. Assuming that you are a miktex user: run on a command line `updmap`.

Comment: I was following the commands found here, completely lost now. I was able to use the font because it is installed in the system.

Comment: found here http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/miamanueva (sorry about that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because your map-files are not up-to-date. As a miktex user run on a command line `updmap`.

Beside this your example is not a suitable use of the font with xelatex and lualatex. Use the font with this engines e.g. like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{miama.otf}
\begin{document}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

See the documentation of fontspec for more examples and commands.

Comment: It should work in the sense that you shouldn't get an error. So run `updmap` -- it will enable the font for pdflatex too.

Comment: Yes it did, I can run my initial code now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like one day to use also with `pdfLaTeX` for [Miama Nueva Font](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/fonts/miama/miama.pdf), you can take this simple code. It works with the engines: `pdfLaTeX`, `XeLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{miama}
\begin{document}
\miama{Right now it's raining in my country after a long time without rain.}
\end{document}
```

[image]